# Inaccurate line counts when reading a file being written concurrently

Tags: python

I have a file that I know is exactly 7168 lines.  Under various conditions, I get bogus line counts.  Take, for example:

```
file = open("testfile", 'r')
count = 0
for line in file:
   count += 1
   print "count: " + str(count)
```

This code results in:
"count: **1098**"

```
file = open("testfile", 'r')
count = 0
for line in file:
   count += 1
   print line  ### this line is the only difference
   print "count: " + str(count)
```

This code results in:
"count: **7168**"

The only thing I can think of is that I'm running out of memory somewhere.  The population of "testfile" comes from a Popen in the background.  The idea/hope is to dump all the required data into a file in the background, before the user reaches a point in the script that requires the dump to be complete.  If the user reaches a point in the script where the content of testfile is needed, but the Popen hasn't completed yet, I run the following code:

```
notified = False
while (os.path.getsize("testfile") == 0):
   if notified == False:
      print "Please hold, still dumping uids..."
      notified = True
print "done!"
```

Suspecting that calling `os.path.getsize` instantly a bazillion times might be detrimental, I modified my code:

```
notified = False
while (os.path.getsize("testfile") == 0):
   if notified == False:
      print "Please hold, still dumping uids..."
      notified = True
   time.sleep(3)   ### Delay 3 seconds
print "done!"
```

In *this* case, my line counts come out as **6896** (which is drastically better, but still not a true count)

Further modification:

```
notified = False
while (os.path.getsize("testfile") == 0):
   if notified == False:
      print "Please hold, still dumping uids..."
      notified = True
   time.sleep(5)   ### Delay 5 seconds
print "done!"
```

Now my line counts come out as **7168** as expected.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on, and how I can achieve my goal with better efficiency?  Overall goal is, my script requires a ton of data be dumped into a file at one point later in the script.  In order to decrease user downtime, my Popen runs in the background at the very start of the script.  The `while (os.path.getsize("testfile") == 0)` line is to prevent a race condition.

Comment: the first step would be to turn off buffering: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: "*The while (os.path.getsize("testfile") == 0) line is to prevent a race condition.*" -- It doesn't.

Comment: But it does prevent a race condition.  The contents are dumped the "testfile" all at once, so if the file size is 0, that means the Popen hasn't completed, and the program should wait for it to finish.

Comment: For what it's worth, thg435's suggestion regarding the disabling of buffering seems to have solved the issue.  If I just add "0" as the last argument to my file opens, the problem no longer occurs.

Comment: Still, even with the buffering value changed, the fact that I could adjust the count value by delaying the while loop suggests that the buffering wasn't the only problem.  Would like to know what my limitations are.

Comment: Strange!  It worked once with buffering set to 0.  Without touching the code at all, I just ran it again, and it gave me a different number.

Comment: That's because you haven't solved the race condition. The data is *not* dumped to the testfile "all at once". It comes into the testfile in dribs and drabs, and your read loop stops because the file is not yet complete. As an alternative, you *could* create the file in one fell swoop -- create `testfile.tmp` and then run `mv testfile.tmp testfile` in your subprocess.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't waiting for the background task to complete. Try replacing your `while` loop executing with this just before you open `testfile`:

```
pid.wait()
```

where `pid` is the return from `subprocess.Popen()`.

---

As an alternative, you could create the file in one fell swoop. For example, you could create `testfile.tmp` and then run `mv testfile.tmp testfile` in your subprocess.

Comment: The reason I am using the Popen at all is precisely that I *don't* want to wait for the background process to complete.

Comment: If you don't wait for the background process to complete, then how can you expect all the file contents, which are provided by that process, to be there?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Because of the while loop in my program that checks for the file size.  In my environment and methods not detailed here (for brevity), the file is dumped all at once.  Therefore if the file size is 0, it's not done yet.  If it's not 0, the process has completed.

Comment: My contention is that "In my environment and methods not detailed here (for brevity), the file is dumped all at once." is wrong, and that in fact the results you're getting are evidence of this.

Answer (score 1):

You have one process writing a file and another process reading the same file. On a multiprocessing system, with no interprocess synchronization, you will get race conditions and thus lower counts than expected. This has nothing to do with the implementation language.

Pipes do a great job of interprocess synchronization. The command:

```
$ producer | tee testfile | wc -l
```

will always produce an exact count by `wc` of exactly the number of lines put into `testfile`. You're making this problem much harder than it ought be.

Comment: There is a while loop in my program which checks for the file size to not be 0.  Utilizing the methods and tools available to me, which are too long to detail here, in my environment, the file is not written to periodically.  It's written elsewhere, then copied all at once.  Therefore if the size is 0, it's not been copied.  If it's not 0, it has been copied (therefore the process is complete).

Comment: A file cannot be copied "all at once". The copy operation itself is non-atomic and takes time to run. It *is* possible to link a file or move a file all at once, but the copy operation takes time, and your while loop runs before it is complete.